# Django search with Whoosh but no Haystack?

Tags: django

I'm just wondering what is exactly the functionality that haystack provides and if I need it.

I mean the search and indexing is done by whoosh. As far as I can tell, haystack is just offering ready made views, and forms. If I want to write my own form and views do I still need haystack?
Am I missing something?

P.S. I don't plan to use any other search engine than whoosh so I also don't need haystacks's multiple search engine wrapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides views, forms and a search engine-agnostic layer, the other powerful thing about Haystack is its ability to map Django models to something the search index understands. Using Haystack, you can easily specify which fields in a model should be indexed and how (see the SearchIndex API - http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html).

Once you have done that, you can then leverage the built-in management commands to (re)index your data when required.

It also comes with some nice templatetags to help present search results, like highlighting the matching bits.

Is there a particular reason that you don't want to use Haystack? It is a pretty non-intrusive plugin that lets you use as much of it as you need, and makes it easy to use more advanced functionality when you need it later down the road. In one of the sites I built, I only used the SearchIndex and SearchQuerySet APIs; I built my own views and forms. Ultimately, if you end up writing your own indexing and searching code, views and forms, you have basically re-written a large part of Haystack, in which case, you may want to consider using something that is in use out there and reasonably well tested.

That said, I have rolled my own 'Haystack' like layer in another project, mainly because the data source didn't map to the Django ORM. In that case, I wrote my own indexing scripts, and used PySolr to interface with my Apache Solr instance.

Given that Whoosh is written in Python, I'd assume it has a decent Python interface, so it shouldn't be too hard to do. I would only do it if there's something special about your scenario though.

Comment: I had a look at Whoosh and I will use it directly. It's simple enough and I like to feel in control :)

Comment: Some services don't support Haystack, for example "Pythonanywhere". In such cases, using Whoosh directly would be the only solution, unless the user is willing to change services.